# Max size of redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is the max size of data I can store in redux? I know the answer may depend on factors, I just need to figure out at what size should I cap it so that I don't have crashes or the likes.

My expected size is not in the order of MBs, but in GBs, so the other answers that I found googling didn't help me.

Comment: I don't know what type of data you are trying to store, but GBs of data in redux store I imagine could crash your app... but might just depend on how your data is structured. Have you had a look at [Redux FAQ: Performance](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#redux-faq-performance) ? I don't think it's a great idea to have GB in memory, what are you trying to do? Can the data be fetched as needed instead of all loaded into memory?

Comment: GB's of data? In what environment is this app going to run?

Comment: I agree with @segFault. It is not a good idea to store GBs of data in redux. Let's say you store 2GB data in store and I don't think the user or application is going to use those 2GB of data in the same time to run the application. Just store what you need and restore after you done with it.

Comment: @segFault Working on a data platform, where I have kind of a many(A)-to-one(B) relation. Discarding A looks wasteful since there is a good probability that another B for the same A is probably going to be accessed. Now if I start storing all the As, then I *might* hit a GB. Not too keen to do the manual GC. Need to check if there is a redux LRU cache already implemented somewhere.